# How can I removed a stuck old Anderson sliding window?

Tags: windows

[This page](https://helpcenter.andersenwindows.com/aw/s/article/Primed-Gliding-Window-Sash-Removal-and-Replacement-1940-1971) shows the kind of window I have and how to remove it.

Problem: one side of the window is stuck and won't come out. The window in question is labeled "left-hand sash" in the illustration and the right side of the window is stuck.

How it works: There are 2 metal pins on the top of the window and two on the bottom (one pin per corner). The pins slide in a groove at the top and bottom. To remove the window, you lift it up so the pins can clear the groove in the bottom sill, which is made of plastic and not removeable without removing the windows.

It appears that the problem is that the space between the top of the window and the casement above it is too small on the right side. Thus I can't lift the window up high enough for the pin to come out of the track in the sill. It's off by about 1/8", I'm guessing. In other words, the window isn't square with the casement. The cause may be swelling of the wood due to humidity, or settling of the house; I don't know.

It's urgent that I remove this window because there's mold in between the double panes and the panes need to be replaced. Any ideas how I can get the stuck corner out? Thank you!

Comment: Might need two people, one to hold the window and one to use a tool(wider is better) to help lift the window.  Sliding(more left or right) window to a better position might help also.  Most instructions usually make it sound easy but often you need more force than expected.  Turn screw with screwdriver by hand, becomes use locking pliers on screwdriver to loosen

Comment: Showing a picture of _your_ window will help people see what's going on in _your_ house and may help them come up with solutions. Otherwise, all we've got is the instructions which don't seem to be helping you.

Comment: Links in answers are disfavored: If Anderson takes their page down, or moves it to another URL, the information contained in the link will disappear, and future readers of the question will be hindered. Including a picture in the question means the information will be preserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your replies. I was able to solve this by cutting a small notch (the size of the pin) in the sill. That allowed the pin to clear the track.

Comment: Thanks for following up with your solution! Be sure to click the check mark as soon as the system will let you so others know this is resolved. I'm not sure how big this notch is, but I hope it hasn't compromised the sill structure or air/water sealing.

Comment: The notch is 3/8" wide and 1/4" deep---tiny. It doesn't affect the function of the window or anything else in the least. Andersen advised me to hire a carpenter to remove the window casing. Heh heh.